# Generate dynamic amount of CollectionType

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I want to create a few `CollectionType` fields.

I have moderators, I load all moderators from db and want to assign sub-users to each modeator in form

Try to do something like that:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    foreach ($options['moderators'] as $mod) {
        $builder
        ->add('users['.$mod->getId().']', CollectionType::class, array(
          'entry_type' => UserFields::class,
          'allow_add' => true,
          'label' => false,
          'entry_options' => array(
          ),
        ));
    }
}
```

In `$options['moderators']` there is array of moderators entities.
I want to create the same amount of `CollectionType` fields as moderators entities (example above - does not work because I cant pass `[]` as field name)

Each moderator have unique id, so I can use it and pass this id to each `CollectionType` but how?

2. How to get back this id of CollectionType in `Controller` function?
3. How to display this form on page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to dive a little deeper into what collections are ;)

Your collection is invalid, because the `entry_type` should be a formType. I'm guessing in your case this should be `EntityType` (if you want the user to choose from a list of users).

So assuming you want a Collection of moderators with each moderator a Collection of sub-users (btw you'd normally make a CRUD and edit each moderator separately, so you don't need a collection with a sub-collection), you'd need something like this:

ModeratorCollectionType.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ModeratorCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('moderators', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => ModeratorType::class,
            'prototype' => true,
            'allow_add' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

ModeratorType.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ModeratorType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('users', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => EntityType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
            ],
            'prototype' => true,
            'allow_add' => true
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Moderator',
        ]);
    }
}
```

In your Controller you'd make a form with the ModeratorCollection

```
$form = $this->createForm(ModeratorCollectionType::class, $data = []);
```

Comment: How to know whoose moderators have specific users? I mean, moderators have id `1` `2` `3`, and how to know where I add users?